# How to cleared the Android MediaPlayer buffer while playing HTTP Live Streaming (HLS).

Tags: android

I was trying to seek to the HLS buffer in android.
Once I send SEEK message to the server, server started sending data from the seek point.
But MediaPlayer keep on playing the present buffer content as it is receiving from sever.
So after doing seek also it is continuing the play and after few second the seek position is getting played as it is there in buffer.

I am not able to free the buffer, So if any body can help me to cleared the buffer.
Or can suggest me the way to access the MediaPlayer buffer while playing HTTP Live Streaming (HLS).

Thanks in advance 
     Kunal

Comment: There is no SEEK message in HLS. What is it that you are actually doing?

Comment: How did you manage to change the stream, I am not able to do that, even if after buffer ends. please share your code.